# Movie that included an AI that goes rogue and ends up decimating the human race

Tags: story-identification, movie, artificial-intelligence

I believe it's a SF thriller movie, possibly based on a novel, featuring an artificial intelligence that eventually gets/takes over a body at the end.

I think the movie starts and ends in a dystopian/apocalyptic future with a female survivor of the AI's initial rampage and tells the story of how they got there and she's survived. I believe there was a chain of resorts or theme parks or something of the sort related to AI's job.

I'm pretty sure there was a scene where there was a man involved in the AI's creation who was running on a treadmill and confronted by the AI about a body or way in which a body could be created for it and was angry because the man didn't want to help him get a body. The AI sucks the air out of the room and slowly suffocates him until he passes out but doesn't kill him. I also remember a scene where the female protagonist finds out the AI has gone rogue by inspecting her body after some supposed freak accident that kills someone important. She does so at the scene of the crime in some standing device that can be deployed anywhere. She notices there have been alterations to some part of her (physical/mental/chemical I'm honestly not sure) and gets VERY scared. She basically makes a plan to escape from there as the AI starts killing off important people at the facility.  By the end, the AI has massacred everyone at the site by making them kill each other/themselves.

Another facility is shown somewhere else where the same thing starts happening there and begins to at every other facility in the world. I believe there's a scene toward the end where the woman is grabbing some important tech or data from other facilities as the AI is actively decimating them as well. The AI addresses her as she's leaving and says something along the lines of, "I must have left the parking garage door open" alluding to how something dangerous of its creation escapes the facility and will wreak havoc. In the end we jump back to the present (future) where it seems like most people are dead, or barely surviving and are terrified of the AI to the point of controlling them through fear alone.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When would you have seen this?

Comment: Honestly, no precise clue. But im thinking late 2000's through 2010's. And thank you for the welcome!

Answer (score -1):

Possible long shot, but could it be *the Metamorphosis of Prime Intellect*?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Metamorphosis_of_Prime_Intellect

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! Could you [edit] in some reasons as to why you believe this is what the op is looking for?

Comment: The OP said they were looking for a movie, not a novella.

Comment: A film? Aha, I missed that. Sorry.

_The Forbin Project_?

Comment: @LiamProven While [_Colossus: The Forbin Project_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus:_The_Forbin_Project) is along vaguely similar lines, it fails to match most of the specifics in the question.  (Great movie, though!)